# Data Structure Terminology?

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, terminology

I have a good amount of questions regarding data structure vocabulary. I'm sure I know what these are/do, but I did not learn the appropriate terms for them or I forgot them, so when someone uses them in an explanation I am confused as to what exactly they mean.

In class we are dealing with hash tables and the terms 'key' and 'bucket' came up. I tried finding out what they mean, and so far what I have understood is that a key refers to an element in the hash table, while a bucket refers to certain place in the hash table.
For example, HashTable[index] refers to a bucket (a 'row' in the hash table, if you will). If that spot in the hash table contains a chain (and the linked list is composed of 'blocks' interconnected), then a key would be a single 'block' in that chain. Is that correct? (As you can tell, I also forgot the term for a 'block' in a linked list)

And on a different topic, we were also dealing with amortized doubling earlier in the year and I have no clue what 'amortized analysis' refers to.

I know some of these might seem like dumb questions but I want to get my terminology right. (I can't stress how frustrating it is when someone uses incorrect terminology when explaining something. Like when my Calc professor refers to 'doing the dot product' as 'marrying the vectors')

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis?

Comment: None of that is really C++ terminology. It's all general terminology regarding data structures and algorithm theory I don't feel like explaining right now, because wikipedia explains it much better.

Comment: some people refer to the linked list entities as nodes

Comment: Invest in a notepad and write these things down. That is what I did at Uni and created my own little dictionary.

Comment: try to have only one question per post.

Comment: Thanks chris. And vmpstr of course! How did I forget?, that was a facepalm. Ed Heal, I do that as well but sometimes the professor goes too fast for me to write it down or skips some terms.

Comment: I completely agree about the frustration. "Marrying the vectors" isn't just non-standard terminology, it's a lousy metaphor; your professor is being "clever" at your expense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually not C++ terminology. C++ has something called an `unordered_map` that provides hash-table-like functionality, but "hash table", "bucket", "key" and the other terms are generic computer-science/programming data-structure and algorithms terminology.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table for more details, and note that C++ is barely mentioned in the article.

Comment: +1, but I'd point out that the C++11 Standard dictates that `unordered_map` et al use *chaining* as the collision resolution mechanism, thereby dictating the use of buckets.  In this way, "bucket" might be considered to be a C++ term, sorta kinda.

Comment: The term bucket is defined and used in the C++ standard: "The elements of an unordered associative container are organized into *buckets*. Keys with the same hash code appear in the same bucket." In fact, there are iterators that only iterate through a single bucket.

Comment: @JohnDibling Only to the same extent that "door" is an automotive term.

Comment: sftrabbit is the only one who provided clear help. Thank you! Everyone else just argued whether or not this is C++ terminology, which I now realize it isn't. And thanks to Dan J for being unnecessarily rude.

Comment: In our defense, I'd just like to point out that your original question was about "C++ Terminology", and we were trying to help you understand C++ terminology. You have since changed the question's title and content. I'm sorry that our answers didn't provide the information that you really wanted.